# The fleet of vehicles is controlled by GPRS. Is or are?

Tags: grammatical-number

"The fleet of vehicles is controlled by GPRS." is or are ? Which is correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ***fleet*** (singular) is the subject here.

Therefore

> The fleet of vehicles ***is*** controlled by (whatever).

Comment: A +1 would be nice. For the speedy delivery, you know.

Comment: How to do that? I'm new here.

Comment: There are two buttons with triangular arrows to the left of my answer, one pointing upward, the other downward. The one pointing upward gives me a +1, the other one a -1. I gave your question a +1 in a similar manner.